# CodeIgniter AJAX Load and Save Form Modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working on simple Insert and Update data form with Ajax and CodeIgniter. Been struggling with this because i'm new in Ajax. The insert method is already work, but when i want to get a data by `id` and update it from the same modal, it won't load.

Here is my code:

*User Controller :*

```
/* Location: ./application/controllers/master/user.php */

function insert() {
   $id_user            = addslashes($this->input->post('id_user'));
   $username           = addslashes($this->input->post('username'));
   $password           = addslashes($this->input->post('password'));
   $email              = addslashes($this->input->post('email'));

   $data = array(
      'username'     => $username,
      'password'     => $password,
      'email'        => $email
   );

   $this->M_user->set_insert($data);
   redirect('master/user');
}

function update() {
   $id_user            = addslashes($this->input->post('id_user'));
   $username           = addslashes($this->input->post('username'));
   $password           = addslashes($this->input->post('password'));
   $email              = addslashes($this->input->post('email'));

   $data = array(
     'username'     => $username,
     'password'     => $password,
     'email'        => $email
   );

   $this->M_user->set_update($id_user,$data);
   redirect('master/user');
}
```

*User Model :*

```
function set_insert($data){
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return TRUE;
}

function set_update($id_user,$data) {     
    $this->db->where('id_user', $id_user);
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data);     
    return TRUE;
}
```

*And here my View:*

```
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">

    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#btnModalForm">Add User</button><br><br>
        [.....]

    <!-- modal data -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal draggable fade" id="btnModalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="btnModalFormLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="btnModalFormLabel"> Data User</h4>
                    </div>

                    <form id="addForm" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('master/user/insert') ?>" class="form-horizontal"> 
                        <table class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" id="btnSaveData" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- modal  data -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->

</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#btnModalForm').on('shown.bs.modal')
            $('#btnModalForm, #btnUpdate').draggable({
                cursor: 'move',
                handle: '.modal-header'
        });  

        $('#btnSaveData').bind('click', function(event) {

            var v_username = $('input:text[name-username]').val();
            var v_password = $('input:text[name-password]').val();
            var v_email    = $('input:text[name-email]').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {username: v_username, password:v_password, email:v_email},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function() {
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    location.reload();
                }
            })
        })  

        $('#btnUpdate').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

            var v_username = $('input:text[name-username]').val();
            var v_password = $('input:text[name-password]').val();
            var v_email    = $('input:text[name-email]').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('master/user/detail') ?>",
                type: "get",
                data: {username: v_username, password:v_password, email:v_email},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // location.reload();
                }
            })
        });
    })
</script>
```

Maybe i was made a wrong code, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error ?? Also user_id not passed from ajax update method.

Comment: No, there is no error, but when the modal is showing up the textfields won't filled by the data

Comment: you need to show your controller with the detail function, the model where you get the information and your whole view because this looks so messy - i don't even understand how the different buttons are working together
and maybe you add some grafics in order to understand what you really want (a screen from your list view and a screen from your modal)